# jQuery UI sortable: is it possible to restrict possible positions of individual elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a list containing different items that needs to be sortable. But there is an additional twist: certain elements are only allowed in specific positions in the list.

**An example** (please look at http://jsfiddle.net/pYL32/2/): There's a list containing elements *foo*, *bar* and *baz* that needs to be sortable; but the item *foo* is only allowed at the top or at the bottom.

So I'm looking for the following behaviour:

1. When I start dragging *foo* downwards and I cross the space between *bar* and *baz*, then the placeholder should jump to the last position after *baz*. When I stop dragging, the *foo* item should be placed at the bottom of the list.
2. When I start dragging *baz* upwards and I cross *foo*, then the placeholder should rest below *foo*. When I stop dragging, the *baz* item should be placed between *foo* and *bar*

Can I somehow achieve this by hooking into the sortable's `change` event that is triggered whenever positions in the list change? Is it possible to revert position changes in a callback to this event?

Or is there another solution to my problem (I would really like to stick with just the jQuery UI library so I'm not looking for solutions using other frameworks/libs)?

Comment: Just wondering whether the answer helped or not...

Comment: Vickel's answer helped. I expanded a bit on it and posted my final solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vickel's answer is solvin my problem almost completely. The only thing that is a bit "ugly" with his solution is that there is no visual feedback during dragging on whether the current position is valid or not. So I went for the following solution:

```
beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
  if(ui.placeholder.index() == 2) return false;
},
change: function(event, ui) {
  if(ui.placeholder.index() == 2) ui.placeholder.addClass('invalid-position');
  else ui.placeholder.removeClass('invalid-position');
}
```

With this solution I check the position of the placeholder every time it changes and I add a class *invalid-position* to the placeholder whenever it is in an invalid position and would be reverted if dropped there.
Based on this *invalid-position* class I then style the placeholder to give visual feedback (e.g. with a red border or background when in an invalid position).

Answer (score 3):

use the widget's `beforeStop` event, detect the position of the placeholder and cancel the event if undesired position

```
beforeStop: function( event, ui ) {
    if(ui.placeholder.index()==2)  return false;
}
```

here the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pYL32/4/), you cannot drag foo to position 2 anymore

I know this is not exactly what you asked, but I found it comes pretty close functionality wise

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for not giving feedback on it earlier... Your answer showed me the right direction and I refined it slightly. See my own answer for the final solution.